# Swift : UIView's shadow is applied to child components

Tags: swift, view, label, shadow

I am developing an app using swift, but I got a strange issue with shadows :

1. I have a UITableViewCell with a view (CTA) that I want to underline with a shadow.
   [image]
2. The view to be underlined references the correct Outlet in my custom UITableViewCell class (CTA -> CTA View)

[image]

3. In my Cell I add a shadow, just like I did for some other views, using this code
   [image]
4. The expected result should be a shadow starting with a offset and looking like a bottom border, what I get is this (the shadow should appears between the first line and the second line) :
   [image]
5. The shadow seems to be applied to the inner views (Label, button, etc) and not the view itself ... First time I see this, I can't figure what is happening and how to fix it.

Have someone already face this ? 
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found out, eventually my view background was CLEARCOLOR, when I changed it to an other color to check the layout, the Inner components shadows disappeared and the view shadow appeared ... seems a transparent view doesn't cast a shadow and label's shadows will be cast on the view behind.